# Testing a method that implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

Tags: debugging, testing, http-post, ihttphandler

So I have a method that implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest. It accepts an HttpContext parameter. This parameter is just a form that is filled out with some XML. Here is the HTML that I am using to generate the post context:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="http://localhost:7703/api.ashx">
<textarea name="XML" id="XML" rows="25" cols="100"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, very simple. This is just used for testing purposes. What I am doing is posting XML in that textbox, and hitting submit. However, I am not sure what to attach my visual studio project to in order to debug. I try attaching it to w3wp.exe like I do when I test the app in a browser and stuff, but that doesn't seem to be working. It still says "This breakpoint will never be hit, no symbols loaded..." blah blah blah, when I put a breakpoint next to the ProcessRequest method and attach.

How do I test this properly?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I attach to the development server at the same port as the post, it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you run this locally you should be able to "run" it from within Visual Studio and VS will automatically attach it self to the correct process.

Comment: This usually never works because we have like a web app with .exe's embedded as click once apps inside so like...whenever I try and just run it, it always try to debug the ClickOnce apps instead.